# In ASP.NET Core - why is app.UsePathBase() failing?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I recently had to move an ASP.NET Core 6.0 website to a new host it now requres a PathBase to work. It worked fine int the old env without pathbase but in the new env it lives in IIS amoung many apps and needs a relative path to get to the correct app after routing to IIS. The app still works a little until a redirect happens, then looses track of the virtual path portion of the URL and the redirected URL is only the `BaseUrl`. I attempted the below code as a remedy but it doesn't make a difference. As soon as a re-direct happens, it goes to the `BaseUrl` and drops the virtual path.

```
 https://{this.Request.Host}/{this.Request.PathBase}
```

After a redirect, it becomes:

```
 https:/{this.Request.Host}
```

Startup.cs extra code that fails to help:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //     . . .
    // string virtualPath = Configuration.GetValue<string>("VirtualPath");
    string virtualPath = "/virt_path";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(virtualPath))
    {
        app.UsePathBase(new PathString(virtualPath));

        app.Map(virtualPath, subApp =>
            {
                subApp.UseRouting();
                subApp.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            });
    }

    // . . .
}
```

I wonder if I'm going to maybe have to include an extra variable in the redirects. Maybe `{this.Request.PathBase}`. I don't like this solution but will try it.

Example of Redirect Code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        if (!InitializePage())
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
        await LoadReportData();
        if (!Report.ReportData.Any())
        {
            . . .
            return RedirectToPage("EmptyReport");
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

Also, for local debug purposes, is the a way to setup my `launchSettings.json` so that it includes a virtual path. As of right now, to test a change, I have to publish to the staging host. This machine is also locked down so that remote debugging is not allowed.

Comment: How you host the application inside the virtual directory? Directly copy the whole application inside it? Are you host it inside the IIS?

Comment: IIS > left panel, uder sites, click on your main web application > right-clk, add application > enter details

Comment: Could you please tell me how you set the redirect in your web application? Please share some codes.

Comment: Example of Redirect provided.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add the prefix path by default, please use below codes:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
   
            return Redirect("~/Index");
       
    
   
    }
```

Then it will work well.